# Magento 2 : search are not relevant

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch

Where should I look (xml file) when :
Search result are bugged in only my theme. ( I have to press 2 times on the arrow "relevance" to get true result).
If I use "Magento Luma", everything is fine.

I tried to search for catalog_search..xml, nothing found.

Magento 2

Comment: Any details on a specific Magento 2 version & what search back end like elasticsearch etc? Also any relevant code should get you a better answer.